# UIViewController with autolayout constraints into a UIPageViewController causes rendering issues

Tags: objective-c, ios7, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to build a constraint based UI, that uses a UIPageViewController for a section of the screen.  That pageViewController is has AutoLayout constraints applied to it, and renders perfectly fine.

However, when I try to put a view controller (lets call it a page) into that pageViewController (using either -setViewControllers:animated: or the datasource methods), the PageViewController gets confused about the content and doesn't render the page.

If I remove the constraints from the page, it renders properly, but that fights my goals of having an autolayout powered UI.

So is there anything special that the UIPageViewController could be doing that would cause AutoLayout to goof up.

For reference - setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints has been turned off for the UIPageViewController and the page before assigning any UILayoutConstraints.

Comment: Hi..did you get any solution of this problem. If yes than please update. I'm facing the same issue but my issue is with iPhone6 and iPhone6 plus only.

Comment: I eventually gave up trying to solve the problem and just wrote a custom page view controller   It was set up as a long "content view" with a gesture recognizer. That content view is masked by its superview. You then place your child VCs on the content view.  The tricky part is now you then have to update the width of the child view controllers when the screen rotates and implement dequeuing if you plan on having a large number of pages.